# How to execute .ps1 files in Windows Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell

How to execute .ps1 files in windows Azure Powershell?
Does windows azure powershell use different extension for batch files?
I have tried .bat and .ps1 extensions without luck. 
Note that I have checked the path of the file and its correct.

Comment: BAT and PS1 Files are completely different. Which are you trying to work with?

Comment: @JustinE anything works. I want to execute script from a file in windows azure powershell.

Comment: http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2011/11/executing-powershell-script-with.html

Comment: What script? What have you tried? And how did that fail to work? Did you get an error?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am trying to start and stop virtual machine using atart-azurevm and stop-azurevm commands. It works when I type in the console. With the file, operation completes successfully -I don't get any errors - but it doesn't starts or stop the vm.

Comment: @JustinE Can you give me links for executing .bat, .txt or .ps1 files? Right now, I am testing powershell scripts in console and I am not yet using visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

1. create a file with notepad and name it test.ps1
2. put your powershell commands in the file, e.g. Start-AzureVM -Name 'myvm' -ServiceName 'myservice'
3. in powershell prompt, type .\test.ps1 and hit enter to run

Alternatively, in powershell ISE load test.ps1 and hit F5 to run. You can set breakpoints, step through line-by-line and check variable contents. You might be better off taking this route.